# play video file from youtube in android

Tags: android, youtube

I have followed a tutorial on how to use the youtube gdata. Populating a listview with videos from youtube and a onclick from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503187/youtube-intent-starts-in-browser-android)

But still video play on youtube not inside my application. Please help me to find this.

Comment: check link given at answer given by me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208439/html5-video-doesnt-play-with-android/10209684#10209684

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you get the You tube url..., Substring the Video_ID from the Url.See the example below i have given.

You can use http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/VIDEO_ID api to get the rtsp link from the actual you tube url.Data is in `XML format`

once you get the rtsp link you can play video in VideoView [here is the example](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/simple-example-using-videoview-to-play.html)

**For example:**
  If this link is the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMM0R19IisI

Then `sMM0R19IisI` is the Video_ID.So you can pass this video id to above api to get the rtsp link

To get Data in `JSON format` use this [http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/"+videoid+"?alt=json](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/%22+videoid%5Bi%5D+%22?alt=json)

Refer these two links:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716146/rtsp-youtube-link)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520313/how-to-get-rtsp-links-android)

Once you get the rtsp link you can play it in `VideoView`

Comment: How i do this in blundell example? what i change on it?

Comment: if you have you tube video link get the Video_ID

Comment: See the answer in that question.., Or if you can get the url you can do in the way i told

Comment: I got https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I88fKt1DL5o&feature=youtube_gdata_player URL.

Comment: and i pass https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=mrencros&v=2&alt=jsonc

Comment: I got https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I88fKt1DL5o&feature=youtube_gdata_player In URL now how i get Video ID from this. I am so confuse about it.

Comment: v=I88fKt1DL5o see in this, I88fKt1DL5o is the Video ID

Comment: Thanks @Abhi but how i get Video ID?

Comment: Try with string operations.., substring after getting the index

Comment: Can you please give me a source code for this same. I got https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=mrEncros&v=2&alt=jsonc I got all videos from my channel in listview. But when i click on particular video then Webview is open. I play that video in videoview not in browser. Its very very need for me. please.

Comment: See [this](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sa=X&ei=z8fhT8WMKM_qrQeetOirAw&ved=0CAYQvwUoAQ&q=get+index+of+particular+string+in+android&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=6b112fb1837e7265&biw=1024&bih=677) and [this](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=get%20substring%20from%20string%20in%20java&oq=Substring%20from%20the%20string%20in%20java&aq=2q&aqi=g-q4&aql=&gs_l=hp.11.2.0i22l4.0.0.2.522.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.qm9c9s5A5EE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=6b112fb1837e7265&biw=1024&bih=677&pf=p&pdl=300)

Comment: I already told you , on click of the list item you have get that particular Url and from thar url get Video_ID.., pass Video_ID my link given in my answer

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(video.getUrl())));  I write this on onvideoclick function. in video.getUrl() what i write to parse video id?

Comment: See my edited answer.., i told everything think it in cool way you will get

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhi i solve it by `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+video.getUrl().split("v=")[1].split("&")[0])));`