# Is there a way to get html5 video (youtube, vimeo, etc) to play in the native video player automatically?

Tags: android, youtube, html5-video, android-videoview, vimeo

I would like to play a HTML5 video back to the user directly in the native android video player.

My current setup takes way too much effort to get into the native video player: Currently I have a WebView with an embedded HTML5 video (such as a Youtube or Vimeo HTML5, not flash, embed). The user has to hit play on the video, and then hit the fullscreen button (on far right in the picture below)

[image]

Then it opens in the native player which looks like this:

[image]

The native player is a View is a much better experience for video playback.  (I believe it is a VideoView? though maybe it is different in newer versions of Android. It is a View within my Activity so provides extra control. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989738/how-to-play-a-video-in-a-webview-with-android) for more info.)

I'm looking for a graceful way of directly launching into this experience instead of having to load the embed in a WebView and then leaving it to the user to tap the full screen button.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Refer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11118002/792232) to play you tube video

Comment: Could you provide code for how you are doing the above? I'm trying to get a Vimeo embed to play fullscreen but it's stubbornly refusing.

Comment: @steemcb it is a little tricky, but check out the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video/4637739

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty I can't seem to get the onShowCustomView event to fire. Are you using an iframe embed? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: @sttemcb I use this for iframe as well as just straight html5 videos. What API level are you on? There are two variants of onShowCustomView, if you are targeting 14+ make sure you override this one as well: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowCustomView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback%29

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty Still nothing, if you have a moment could you stick up a gist so I can see where I might be going wrong? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty Actually never mind, turns out the view hierarchy I was placing the webview in was causing an issue somewhere. I stripped it back and am now getting the callbacks. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @steemcb glad to hear it