# Not getting list of YouTube videos

Tags: android, android-emulator, youtube, youtube-api

I have followed a tutorial on how to use the youtube gdata. Populating a listview with videos from youtube and a onclick. The source code is available on:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/click-item-in-a-listview-to-show-youtube-video/

Once i have changed the YouTube GData link

from:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author="+username+"&v=2&alt=jsonc

to :

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads

i am not getting list of videos, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is it's not working because :

**From this URL :**

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author="+username+"&v=2&alt=jsonc

you are getting JSON String in Response for gdata.youtube.com

and

**In this URL :**

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads

you are getting Rss XML in Response for gdata.youtube.com

**SOLUTION :**

to make it working you will need to change JSON String parsing in `GetYouTubeUserVideosTask` class to XML parsing

**OR**

use this URL for getting data in JSON format :

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc

and use this tutorial to known how we parse json in android :

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: hI Bhaiya with your guidance i have searched and now i am trying to make it, thanks for help i will try it...

Comment: if I only want to get JSON String in Response for gdata.youtube.com, so what url i have to write

Comment: @Udhikriman : what you are sending here "+username+" for getting json

Comment: buddy as i earlier asked i want to fetch videos using this url : http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL34F010EEF9D45FB8, so here is my another question how can i get json gdata url for the same

Comment: Yes i am sending here "+username+" for getting json

Comment: Thanks dear,again you have made my day, but still small doubt in my mind, like for this url : http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL34F010EEF9D45FB8  how can i get json gdata url to use

Comment: @Udhikriman : i think it's not possible to get data from [this](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL34F010EEF9D45FB8) url as JSOn or xml but i'm trying if found any thing then update to u

Comment: i hope brother you will find a way to get JSON data for that url...much needed

Comment: By using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503187/youtube-intent-starts-in-browser-android i am able to view selected video in another activity but whenever i click upon video to run it is not running and getting black screen....why?

Comment: @Udhikriman : make a new question with your code then we will see what's going wrong

Comment: please browse this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947223/how-to-run-youtube-video-in-android-emulator

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect code for new google api version 3

```
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

  var channelName = 'PochicaKing';

  $.get(
          "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
            part: 'contentDetails',
            forUsername: channelName,
//            mine: true,
//            access_token: 'ya29.cQEoJbvUmAMT6xJFgDoi4gq0EW8O5Q_9ZqLtNUay0AbNh-mldmNh5mlicarLx00AHxL_O6Vur8M3Bw',
            key: 'AIzaSyARSqGexKgNt0BdHUJBXg2pnxMGgYXrszw'
          },
  function (data) {

    $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
      console.log(item);
      pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.likes;
      gitVids(pid);
    });

  }
  );

  function gitVids(pid) {

    $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", {
              part: 'snippet',
              maxResults: 5,
              playlistId: pid,
              key: 'AIzaSyARSqGexKgNt0BdHUJBXg2pnxMGgYXrszw'
            },
    function (data) {

      var output;
      $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
//      console.log(item);
        vidTitle = item.snippet.title;
        vidId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;

        output = '<li><iframe width="420" height="315"src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vidId + '"></iframe></li>'
        $('#results').append(output);
      });

    }
    );



  }

});   

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="results"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Api V2 is opsolete.
Use V3
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=**QUERY**&maxResults=50&key=**YOURKEYGOOGLECONSOLE**

Comment: The format is bad, and usually stack overflow doesn't support link only answers as links usually expire. Add some examples if possible.