# How to run YouTube Video in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, youtube, youtube-api

I have made a program in which i am fetching list of youtube videos in listview and i have implemented onClick also

source:- I have followed a tutorial on how to use the youtube gdata. Populating a listview with videos from youtube and a onclick. The source code is available on:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/click-item-in-a-listview-to-show-youtube-video/

**Problem:**

Whenever i click on any of the youtube video item row, getting specific video in next activity but whenever i click on video to run it is not working everytime getting only black space

**GetYouTubeUserVideosTask.java**

```
 public class GetYouTubeUserVideosTask implements Runnable {

 public static final String LIBRARY = "Library";

 private final Handler replyTo;

 private final String username;


    public GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(Handler replyTo, String username) {
this.replyTo = replyTo;
this.username = username;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
try {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet
           ("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/
            GoogleDevelopers/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");
    // Get the response that YouTube sends back
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    // Convert this response into a readable string
    String jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString
            (response.getEntity().getContent());
    // Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    // Get are search result items
    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");

    // Create a list to store are videos in
    List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        // The title of the video
        String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
        // The url link back to YouTube, this checks if it has a mobile url
        // if it doesnt it gets the standard url
        String url;
        try {
    url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
        } catch (JSONException ignore) {
    url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
        }

    String thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject
            ("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");

        // Create the video object and add it to our list
        videos.add(new Video(title, url, thumbUrl));
    }
    // Create a library to hold our videos
    Library lib = new Library(username, videos);
    // Pack the Library into the bundle to send back to the Activity
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putSerializable(LIBRARY, lib);

    // Send the Bundle of data (our Library) back to the handler (our Activity)
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.setData(data);
    replyTo.sendMessage(msg);

// We don't do any error catching, just nothing will happen if this task falls over
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.e("Feck", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Feck", e);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("Feck", e);
}
    }
```

**VideosListView.java**

```
  public class VideosListView extends 
  ListView implements    android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private List<Video> videos;
private VideoClickListener videoClickListener;

public VideosListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public VideosListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public VideosListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void setVideos(List<Video> videos){
    this.videos = videos;
    VideosAdapter adapter = new VideosAdapter(getContext(), videos);
    setAdapter(adapter);
    // When the videos are set we also set an item click listener to the list
    // this will callback to our custom list whenever an item it pressed
    // it will tell us what position in the list is pressed
    setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

// Calling this method sets a listener to the list
// Whatever class is passed in will be notified when the list is pressed
// (The class that is passed in just has to 'implement VideoClickListener'
// meaning is has the methods available we want to call)
public void setOnVideoClickListener(VideoClickListener l) {
    videoClickListener = l;
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
}

// When we receive a notification that a list item was pressed
// we check to see if a video listener has been set

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
    if(videoClickListener != null){
        videoClickListener.onVideoClicked(videos.get(position));
    }
}
```

**VideoClickListener.java**

```
 public interface VideoClickListener {

public void onVideoClicked(Video video);

  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Emulator wont play youtube videos, because youtube having different different formats, emulator supports only 3gp videos, you can test it in mobile it will work fine.

Comment: yes i tried only 3gp video will work, if you test in mobile youtube videos also will work

Comment: you can check in mobile, suppose you wont view video then you can play video by using Players(no of players in google paly), or you can play the video using iframe.

Answer (score 1):

i tried this code and with this i can watch youtube videos. so try this code and tell me about your status.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @ Override


     public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super. onCreate (savedInstanceState);



         setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

         WebView web = (WebView) findViewById (R.id.webView1);
         web. getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
         web. getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically (false);
         web. getSettings().setPluginsEnabled (true);
         web. getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows (false);
         web. getSettings().setSupportZoom (false);
         web. setVerticalScrollBarEnabled (false);
         web. setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled (false);


         web. loadUrl ("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wg65ohhDldc");

         web. setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient () {
             @ Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             if (url.startsWith("vnd.youtube")){

             startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

             return true;
             }
             else
             {
             return false;
             }
             }
         });
     }

 }
```